# SELECT Created.at FROM Orders LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Created.at' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This might be too elementary but I was confused with why I'm getting an error for the following simple query:

```
SELECT Created.at
FROM Orders;
```

16:34:16    SELECT Created.at FROM Orders LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Created.at' in 'field list'   0.148 sec

There is clearly a column in my Orders table called "Created.at"

[image]

Is this an incompatible column name? Please let me know.

Comment: Is this an incompatible column name? - yes it is. Full stops in sql delineate db object nodes eg table name followed by column name - in your example created appears to be a table name and at a column in that table see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html and the published answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
SELECT `Created.at`
FROM Orders;
```